# image_style_url() function not giving proper image in drupal 7

Tags: hooks

I am using `image_style_url()` function in drupal 7 with custom style. In my custom style I have taken a height:200 and width:200. But its cropping my image with these style not re-sizing it.

```
$query_bigimg = db_query(" select * from  {node} WHERE  type =  'cont' ORDER BY nid ASC LIMIT 0 , 1 ");
foreach($query_bigimg as $data) {
  $data_nid = $data->nid;
  $_Data = node_load($data_nid);
  $_bigImg = $_Data->field_ua_news_photo['und'][0]['uri'];
  $_styles = 'big';
```

`<img src="<?php print image_style_url($_styles,$_bigImg); ?>" class="big-img img-hover">`

Comment: Please add a code sample.

Comment: <?php 
               $query_bigimg = db_query(" select * from  {node} WHERE  type =  'cont' ORDER BY nid ASC LIMIT 0 , 1 ");   
                foreach($query_bigimg as $data){
                  $data_nid = $data->nid;
                  $_Data = node_load($data_nid);
                  $_bigImg = $_Data->field_ua_news_photo['und'][0]['uri'];
                  $_styles = 'big';
              ?>
<img src="<?php print image_style_url($_styles,$_bigImg); ?>" class="big-img img-hover">
              <?php } ?>

Answer (score 3):

Then it is likely the rule you are referencing is not configured to do what you want it to do. It may be cropping instead of scaling or do a scale and crop.

Edit the image style at: admin/config/media/image-styles/edit

Check to see if it is scaling or cropping. Adjust it or create a new one and reference that in your code.

Comment: I am using this code on my tpl file like this:
$_styles = 'tumb_new';
$_bigimg  = image path;
image_style_url($_styles,$_bigImg);

Comment: What is the value of $_styles?

Comment: machine name of my style..That I configured on drupal admin
Home » Administration » Configuration » Media » Image styles